# Web.Contents failed to get contents in Get Data from Web

Tags: microsoft-excel, web

I am trying to get data from a website in Excel by using the Get Data from Web functionality in Excel. It generally works through the following window:[image]

So generally, I just enter the url and click on OK to go to that website. When I am trying to do the same thing with the website [www.equibase.com](https://www.equibase.com/), it is giving me the error as below:
[image]

Can someone please guide me how to solve this problem and what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This means that web resource does not support pulling data in that way.

[405 not allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405)